# regular expressions / pattern matching on ubuntu command line

Tags: bash

I notice a lot of bash utilities like `ls`, `cp`, `mv`, `grep` use regular expressions and pattern matching. For instance symbols like * [] {} etc.

However, I find this to be different in some regard to other regular expression tutorials I find on the Internet. Is there a specific standard that these utilities follow or a comprehensive list of shortcuts somewhere?

Thank you

Comment: They're [shell globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) rather than regular expressions

Comment: That's helpful. And so I'm guessing grep doesn't follow glob then since its man page speaks about some other standard of regular expressions?

Comment: `grep` is a different case: it *does* use regular expressions for matching. The other commands that you mentioned don't do pattern matching themselves, but may accept command-line arguments that are constructed by the shell using globbing. I'm unclear which usage you are asking about - do you have some specific examples?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While similar, the wildcard patterns that you’re referring to are not regular expressions; they are [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) and in this context, **shell patterns**. They are expanded by the shell itself – not by commands such as `ls`, `cp`, etc. Just to clarify, these commands are not actually “bash utilities”; they are programs that can be executed by *any* shell.

When a command is typed in a shell, the shell parses the tokens (words) and one of the things it does is expand *glob patterns* into appropriate filenames. In the most common case, these filenames are then provided by the shell as a list of arguments for the command being invoked.

#### Standardisation

These shell patterns have been standardised for Unix-like operating systems in the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)
specification: [Pattern Matching Notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13).

Some shells (Bash and the Korn shell) go further and extend these patterns to implement *extended globs*. For more information, see the relevant section on [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob).