# How do you match any character in bash regex?

Tags: bash, scripts, regex

In a bash script, why does

```bsh
message='123456789'
echo "${message//[0-9]/*}"
```

display `*********`

but

```bsh
message='123456789'
echo "${message//./*}"
```

displays `123456789`?

All the documentation I've seen says that `.` matches any character in regex, even in bash, but it's not working for me. How do you match any character in bash?

Comment: Related: [regular expressions / pattern matching on ubuntu command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775216/regular-expressions-pattern-matching-on-ubuntu-command-line)

Answer (score 5):

Where in the documentation does it say that `.` means *any character*
in pattern matching? In `man bash` it says:

```
 Pattern Matching

   Any character that appears in a pattern, other than the special
   pattern characters described below, matches itself.  The NUL
   character may not occur in a pattern.  A backslash escapes the
   following character; the escaping backslash is discarded when
   matching.  The special pattern characters must be quoted if
   they are to be matched literally.

   The special pattern characters have the following meanings:
      *      Matches any string, including the null string.
             When the globstar shell option is enabled, and
             is used in a pathname expansion context, two
             adjacent *s used as a single pattern will match
             all files and zero or more directories and
             subdirectories.  If followed by a /, two
             adjacent s will match only directories and
             subdirectories.

      ?      Matches any single character.
```

Regular expressions is not the same as shell pattern matching:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439875/why-not-seeing-shell-globs-as-a-dialect-of-regex.
If you want to replace all characters with another character using
`${parameter/pattern/string}` syntax in Bash you need to use `?` like
that:

```
$ echo "${message//?/*}"
*********
```

You could use `.` instead of `?` in programs that use regular
expressions such as `sed`:

```
$ sed 's,.,*,g' <<< "$message"
*********
```

Comment: I can use `.` instead of `.`? How does that work?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @CJDennis: ok, sorry, I meant `you could use . instead of ?`. I fixed it.